# Graph Plotting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cpu-architecture

I am trying to understand the below part of the code. Please help:

```
sendBandwidth = (sizes./sendTimes)/1e9;
[maxSendBandwidth,maxSendIdx] = max(sendBandwidth);
fprintf('Achieved peak send speed of %g GB/s\n',maxSendBandwidth)
gatherBandwidth = (sizes./gatherTimes)/1e9;
[maxGatherBandwidth,maxGatherIdx] = max(gatherBandwidth);
fprintf('Achieved peak gather speed of %g GB/s\n',max(gatherBandwidth))
```

In the code above why we are dividing the bandwidth with `1e9` ?
What this `[maxSendBandwidth,maxSendIdx] = max(sendBandwidth);` line of code is doing?

and while plotting

```
hold off
semilogx(sizes, sendBandwidth, 'b.-', sizes, gatherBandwidth, 'r.-')
hold on
semilogx(sizes(maxSendIdx), maxSendBandwidth, 'bo-', 'MarkerSize', 10);
semilogx(sizes(maxGatherIdx), maxGatherBandwidth, 'ro-', 'MarkerSize', 10);
grid on
title('Data Transfer Bandwidth')
xlabel('Array size (bytes)')
ylabel('Transfer speed (GB/s)')
legend('Send to GPU', 'Gather from GPU', 'Location', 'NorthWest')
```

why we using this b.- and bo-, and this 4th argument 10 ?

Comment: Did you check the documentation for `semilogx`? I'm sure the `b.-` and `bo-` arguments are explained very thoroughly there. In case you're unfamiliar with MATLAB, `'MarkerSize', 10` is a name-value argument. Why have you added the [tag:cpu-architecture] tag?

Comment: Because code is about finding the Speed Transfer rate of GPU, I am not sure which formula they using for 1e9?

Comment: How many bytes are in a gigabyte?

Comment: Also I wen through the semilogx documentation https://www.mathworks.com/help/rf/ref/semilogx.html didnt find b.- or bo- , ro-

Comment: 1e9 bytes are in gigabytes, waow thank you

Comment: Try this one instead: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html. Specifically, have a look at [LineSpec](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html#bqulach-14_sep_mw_3a76f056-2882-44d7-8e73-c695c0c54ca8).

Comment: `[maxSendBandwidth, maxSendIdx] = max(sendBandwidth);` returns the maximum of `sendBandwidth` and the index of these maximum. See Matlab documentation of `max`: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html